# why is my express middleware session undefined?

Tags: session, express, middleware

I'm trying to use the express middleware for sessions (I'm not understanding but I feel that I am very close).

the reason I have ended up asking is that the express docs (http://expressjs.com/api.html#middleware) are calling it express.cookieSession where as everyone else (mostly on here) Ive seen discussing it have been calling it express.session. I'm really not sure now, I just have a big lump of possibly useful code ???  but every example I see is different ... how does it work?

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http');
  , app = express();


store  = new express.session.MemoryStore;
app.use(express.cookieParser());
//app.use(express.cookieSession());
app.use(express.session({secret:'whateverman',key:'express.sid',store:store}));
app.use(app.router);

app.all('/*',function(req,res,next){res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","X-Requested-With");next();});



var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);



io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){

    socket.on('reglogin',function(_){_.session.e='some@email.com';});

});
```

socket.on('reglogin' produces:

TypeError: Cannot set property 'e' of undefined

//-------------------------------update on question

if express is dependant on connect but express can access connects middleware as if it were its own, eg:

```
app.use(express.cookieSession()); //app is express
app.use(connect.cookieSession()); //does exactly the same
```

then surely the same logic would apply to socket.io which is dependant on express:

```
io.use(connect.CookieSession()); //io is socket.io
```

Am I wrong here? does Socket.io have the same .use method? update:(answer is no to io.use)

io.interoperate(app.use(express.cookieSession())); LOL

----------------------------UPDATE---------------------------------
I've followed the following npm modules guide lines in a despirate attemp to get sessions working and filed each and every time on handshake with no cookie:

express.io
session.socket.io
session.io + sessionstore

currently using the latter with console log:

```
warn - handshake error Could not find cookie with key: connect.sid
```

Comment: In Express 2, it's `session`; in Express 3, `cookieSession`. That explains the disconnect between what you see on the website (`cookieSession`) and everywhere else (`session`); everywhere else it's outdated.

Comment: well express is dependent on connect. in connect/lib/middleware i see both session.js and cookieSession.js i'm not seeing the light...

Comment: I think it's because i'm using the req from io not app, io is only listening to app (app is express), but that is only a theory

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that's the problem too. I found a way to make it interoperate with Express 2, but I haven't found anything for Express 3.

Comment: interesting, what did you do with express 2?

Comment: I searched for "Socket.IO session" and found [this blog post](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/).

Comment: very nice @icktoofay i will be trying to impliment this for express3 tomorrow and will update this question (hopfully with an answer).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29049/discussion-between-ben-muircroft-and-icktoofay)